# Web browser control end-of-life?

Tags: c#, sdk, webkit, webbrowser-control, microsoft-edge

According to this [link](https://news.softpedia.com/news/microsoft-officially-announces-the-end-of-internet-explorer-532969.shtml) Microsoft finally annoces the end of IE. It doesn't come as a surprise, they have been talking about that for a long time. But what about the built in web browser control? Altough we have alternatives today, we still have old versions running out there with the web browser control based on IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **IE mode** in Edge to support ActiveX control and Browser Helper Objects. For more information about what IE mode supports, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality).

For more information about IE retirement FAQ, you can refer to [this official blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).

Comment: Perfect, thanks to the official blog I was able to find that MSHTML (Trident) engine will continue to be supported.

Comment: I looked around at those links but have yet to find any information on how to use the WebBrowser (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) object with Edge. Have you seen anything specific?

Comment: I'm using C++, but I guess it's the same for .NET. Take a look at the section "What is the MSHTML (Trident) engine? How does that relate to IE mode?" They recommend us to move WebView2. This works with the latest version of Edge, based on Chrome.